# What causes AWS SageMaker kmeans predict method to output a 413 Request Entity Too Large error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, k-means, amazon-sagemaker

I am attempting to create an Unsupervised Machine Learning Model using the k-means algorithm in AWS SageMaker. I am getting a 413 Request Entity Too Large error when calling the kmeans predictor predict method. What causes such an error? I have searched and most responses talk about Elastic Beanstalk and nginx settings which doesn't apply to my case.

The relevant code and error can be seen below and my entire Jupyter Notebook can be found at (https://github.com/bgaber/machine-learning-recommendation-engine-with-aws-sagemaker/blob/main/imdb-movie-recommendation.ipynb). The complete error can be seen at the bottom of the Jupyter notebook. I have looked in CloudWatch Logs, but it did not provide anymore specific information.

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
df_scaled=pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df))
df_scaled.columns=df.columns
df_scaled.index=df.index
train_data = df_scaled.values.astype('float32')
role = get_execution_role()
bucket_name = 'bg-sagemaker-bucket'
num_clusters = 15
kmeans = KMeans(role=role,
                train_instance_count=1,
                train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                output_path='s3://'+ bucket_name +'/kmeans-project/',              
                k=num_clusters)

kmeans.fit(kmeans.record_set(train_data))    
kmeans_predictor = kmeans.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, 
                                 instance_type='ml.t2.medium')
result=kmeans_predictor.predict(train_data)

Error:
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (413) from model with message "
413 Request Entity Too Large
Request Entity Too Large
The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.
```

Comment: Did you find anything for this Bro, getting the same errors.

Comment: Yes, I did get the answer and I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the "kmeans_predictor.predict", it means you will invoke the Sagemaker endpoint to process the prediction. In the AWS document I found "Maximum payload size for endpoint invocation = 5 MB", which means when the prediction dataset is too big (the payload size exceed 5MB), you will get the "HTTP 413 Payload Too Large" response.

My solution was to split data in two parts and invoke the endpoint twice to get two predictions, then I combined the two results into one in order to fit the original format.

Example:

```
train_data1 = train_data[0:40000]
train_data2 = train_data[40000:]
result1=kmeans_predictor.predict(train_data1)
result2=kmeans_predictor.predict(train_data2)
result = result1 + result2
```